# How to inlcude empty data GEE (R, reticualte)

Tags: r, google-earth-engine

I am using the r package reticulate and rgee to run some analyses in Google Earth Engine and get data loaded into r via numpy arrays for further analyses. I came across one issue that I could not solve. I tried to compile a simple example (see below). The issue is, that for some dates the vectors that I am extracting are not of the same length, although they are coming from the very same image. I assume that missing values get discarded and not transferred. Sometimes it is different for the different bands. In this case all three bands that I am extracting are different to the lon/lat vector. Any idea how to include missing values or whether the problem is actually something else.

```
#### Initialise GEE 
library(rgee)  
library(reticulate)

use_condaenv("gee-demo", conda = "auto",required = TRUE)

ee = import("ee")
ee$Initialize()

np = import("numpy")
pd = import("pandas")


# region of interest
roi = ee$Geometry$Rectangle(c(5, 50, 10, 55))

# load MODIS collection
Mod09       = ee$ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD09GA")$
                filterDate(ee$Date('2016-01-01'), ee$Date(paste0('2016-12-31')))$
                filterBounds(roi)

# get dates
date <- sapply(Mod09$getInfo()[[6]], function(x) x$properties$`system:index`)


Mod09sub = ee$Image(Mod09$toList(length(date))$get(3))$select(
    list("sur_refl_b01",
         "sur_refl_b03",
         "sur_refl_b04"))

latlng = ee$Image$pixelLonLat()$addBands(Mod09sub)
latlng = latlng$reduceRegion(reducer = ee$Reducer$toList(),
                               geometry = roi,
                               scale = 500)

# convert lat lon values to numpy array
lats = np$array((ee$Array(latlng$get("latitude"))$getInfo()))
lngs = np$array((ee$Array(latlng$get("longitude"))$getInfo()))
### length(lats): 1238793
### length(lngs): 1238793  

# convert band values to numpy array
red   = np$array((ee$Array(latlng$get("sur_refl_b01"))$getInfo()))
blue  = np$array((ee$Array(latlng$get("sur_refl_b03"))$getInfo()))
green = np$array((ee$Array(latlng$get("sur_refl_b04"))$getInfo()))
## length(red): 1238792  

df <- data.frame(x = lngs, y = lats, red, green, blue)

r <- raster:::rasterFromXYZ(df)
plotRGB(r, stretch = "lin")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean that you get different count for the `latitude` and `longitude` bands compared to `sur_refl_b01`, `sur_refl_b03`, and `sur_refl_b04`? That would probably be because you have some masked pixels. You can either unmask the pixels or make sure `latitude` and `longitude` get the same mask. *Note that I'm not an R developer and am unable to test if this work*, but the general ideas should be OK.

To unmask (to -1 in this case):

```
latlng = ee$Image$pixelLonLat()$addBands(Mod09sub$unmask(-1))
```

Alternatively, make sure `pixelLonLat()` also get masked:

```
latlng = ee$Image$pixelLonLat()$addBands(Mod09sub)$updateMask(Mod09sub$select(0))
```

Comment: $unmask() is doing the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can mask the lon-lat image to have the same mask as the other images. That would be `ee.Image.pixelLonLat().updateMask(Mod09sub.select('sur_refl_b01'))` in JavaScript or Python; I'm not familiar with R to confidently translate it but it does look like you turn the `.`s into `$`s.

Another possibility would be to convert all of the bands you wish to retrieve (both original image data and lonlat) into an array using `ee.Image.toArray()`. That way there's only one mask, and your reduce will get you an `ee.List` of `ee.Array`s instead of several lists. But you'll have to fetch the lat, lon, and bands out by index instead of name.

Finally, you could consider downloading a raster image instead of reducing into a list; that will be much more efficient on the Earth Engine servers and able to scale to larger datasets.

Comment: Well, I tried with img$getDownloadUrl() with subsequent unzip and load into R, but this was much slower than using the above approach. Maybe there is a better raster download option?

Comment: @SimeonL If image downloads are slower that's surprising and might be worth a bug report. (But it might be that your image version was actually not equivalent for some reason; I can't say.)